# (PHP) Javascript confirmation alert

Tags: javascript, php

can you help me with this? I want a confirmation alert before executing the delete query but i dont know how to pass variable from my js

```js
function removeAppointment() {
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this appointment?")) {
    location.href="remove-appointment.php?" //passing the id but how?
  }
}
```

```html
<!--I WANT TO HAVE A CONFIRMATION BEFORE DELETING THE ITEM-->
<a href="remove-appointment.php?remove='.$id.'"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i> Remove</button></a>

<!--BUT WITH SPECIFIC ID FROM MY TABLE-->
<a onclick="removeAppointment()"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i> Remove</button></a>
```

Comment: Not related to the question but your HTML is **Error:** The element `button` must not appear as `a` descendant of the a element. Use [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) to validate your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answer: Your HTML is **Error:** The element `button` must not appear as `a` descendant of the a element. (Use [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) to validate your HTML.)

You can use many ways to show confirm dialog before continue.
These two use event listener and `onclick` HTML attribute.

#### Use JavaScript event listener.

Your PHP, or HTML displaying page.

```php
<a id="remove-link" href="remove-appointment.php?remove=<?=$id; ?>">Remove</a>
<button id="remove-button" type="button" data-link="remove-appointment.php?remove=<?=$id; ?>">Remove</button>
```

Your JS.

```js
window.onload = () => {
    // for use with link
    let removeLink = document.getElementById('remove-link');
    removeLink.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            // confirmed.
            // let the link continue. do nothing here.
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();// stop link.
        }
    });

    // for use with button
    let removeBtn = document.getElementById('remove-button');
    removeBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            // accepted.
            let linkTo = removeBtn.dataset.link;
            window.location.href = linkTo;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}
```

#### Use `onclick` attribute.

This is almost the same with event listener.

```php
<a id="remove-link" href="remove-appointment.php?remove=<?=$id; ?>" onclick="return askConfirmLink();">Remove</a>
<button id="remove-button" type="button" data-link="remove-appointment.php?remove=<?=$id; ?>" onclick="return askConfirmButton();">Remove</button>
```

```js
function askConfirmLink() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


function askConfirmButton() {
    let removeBtn = document.getElementById('remove-button');
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        let linkTo = removeBtn.dataset.link;
        window.location.href = linkTo;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The difference on these 2 (`a`, `button`) is `a` you can let it continue the link but `button` you must use JS `window.location.href` to redirect the link.

See all 2 methods in action on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xn68f70k/).

---

Tips:

To make `<a>` link display like a button, you have to specify in CSS. You may know this but it is for everyone else.

```css
a, 
button {
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: .85rem;
    padding: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">This button is A</a>
<button type="button">This button is BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: YES! I I think I just didn't notice that my button was enclosed with an a tag. But yeah, you're a life saver. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Noobgrammer If my answer is work for you, you can click on accept the answer.

Comment: okay okay done im sorry im new here :D

Answer (score -1):

Why you need the removeAppointment.php file? i think the js function can handle that just to deleting a table record, and you can go to the same page as reload the page after deleting proccess at the js function.

Comment: <script>
        function removeAppointment(idToDelete) {
            if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this appointment?")) {
                // delete proccess where id='idToDelete'
              location.href="index.php" //and then go to the same page (which mean just for reload after deleting)
            }
          }

      <a onclick="removeAppointment($row['id'])"><button>Remove</button></a>

Comment: I already tried it but my php doens't read my echo script alert that's why I need to find an alternative way.